# Recurrence relation: $c_{k+1}=c_k+\frac{1}{(k+1)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, recurrence-relations, closed-form

I have no idea how to proceed solving a recurrence relation like this. I know that the terms approach $e$ but beyond that I have no idea. The relation is$$c_{k+1}=c_k+\frac{1}{(k+1)!} \ \ ; \ c_0=1$$

Addendum. I would like an answer in any form other than the sum form.

Comment: Exactly what do you want? To express $c_k$ as a function on $k$?

Comment: Yes, but is there even another meaning of the word "solve" in this context?

Comment: You have that $c_n = \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{1}{k!}$, but there's no closed form for this sum.  As you note, this approaches $e$, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may write
$$
c_{k+1}-c_k=\frac{1}{(k+1)!}
$$ then sum from $k=0$ to $k=n$ to obtain, **by telescoping**,
$$
c_{n+1}-c_0=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{(k+1)!}
$$ or
$$
\bbox[20px,border:1px solid #FF9933]{c_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}, \quad n\geq0.} \tag1
$$

If you want an expression without a sum, you may write

> $$
> \bbox[20px,border:1px solid #FF9933]{c_n=\frac{\left\lfloor n!\:e\right\rfloor}{n!}, \quad n\geq1.} \tag2
> $$

where $e$ is the real number such that $\ln e=1$ and where $\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor$ stands for the integer part of $x$.

Comment: I have the feeling that OP already knew this... But I doubt that there is a simpler expression.

Comment: It has a simpler expression if you use the incomplete gamma function.

Comment: Well, I'd not call such a expression "simpler" :)

Comment: I did, unfortunately, already know this. If it makes anything easier, the sequence of $c_k$'s produces the coefficients in the power series representation of $\frac{e^z}{1-z}$

Comment: But I would actually like to see that expression. I wanted an answer in any form other than the sum form.

Comment: @JacksonFitzsimmons Here is a different expression. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, but do you mind showing how you arrived at this?

Comment: @JacksonFitzsimmons You may deduce it from $$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}<e<\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}+\frac1{n\:n!}, \quad n\geq1$$ giving $$n!\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}<n! \:e<n!\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}+\frac1{n}, \quad n\geq1.$$ Observe that $\displaystyle n!\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}$ is an integer...